# How to drop all foreign keys from a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to drop the all foreign keys that have the following conditions.

```
SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('Table1', 'Table2')
  AND CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE '%FK__%__DL%'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a table named `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` which stores all tables constraints. constraint type of `FOREIGN KEY` is also keeps in that table. So by filtering of this type you can reach to all foreign keys.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE   CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'
```

If you create a dynamic query (for `DROP`-ing the foreign key) in order to alter the table, you can reach to the aim of altering the constraints of all tables.

```
WHILE(EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' AND TABLE_NAME IN ('Table1', 'Table2') AND CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE '%FK__%__DL%'))
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql_alterTable_fk NVARCHAR(2000)

    SELECT  TOP 1 @sql_alterTable_fk = ('ALTER TABLE ' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.[' + TABLE_NAME + '] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + CONSTRAINT_NAME + ']')
    FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
    WHERE   CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'
            AND TABLE_NAME IN ('Table1', 'Table2')
            AND CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE '%FK__%__DL%'

    EXEC (@sql_alterTable_fk)
END
```

`EXISTS` function with its parameter assures that there is at least one constrain for foreign key.

Comment: Thanks for your help
How can I Drop All Foreign keys WHERE   TABLE_NAME IN ( 'Table1', 'Table2' ) AND CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE '%FK__%__DL%'

Comment: Msg 3728, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
'FK__Stock__DL3__6E0C4425' is not a constraint.
Msg 3727, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.

Comment: Do you get any record by executing the following query?
`SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'FK__Stock__DL3__6E0C4425'`

Comment: Execute the following query: `SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'FK__Stock__DL3__6E0C4425'`.
And then try to execute this one: `ALTER TABLE [TABLE_SCHEMA].[TABLE_NAME] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK__Stock__DL3__6E0C4425]`.
Is it possible to drop? (Don't forget to replace the names of `TABLE_SCHEMA` and `TABLE_NAME`!

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what Siyavash suggested, but I prefer a bit more control over the process..

If you use this query:

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', TABLE_SCHEMA, '.[', TABLE_NAME, '] DROP CONSTRAINT [', CONSTRAINT_NAME, ']')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'
```

Run it; it generates a list of drop commands for every FK in the DB. You can then either pick out the ones you want to execute or you can add more clauses the the `WHERE` to restrict further

As with all "SQL that writes SQL" you run it by copying the results out of the grid, pasting into a new window in SSMS and running them (F5)

Hence, your query, with the `CONCAT` that writes the drop command:

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', TABLE_SCHEMA, '.[', TABLE_NAME, '] DROP CONSTRAINT [', CONSTRAINT_NAME, ']')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('Table1', 'Table2')
  AND CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE '%FK__%__DL%'
```