# how to delete all foreign keys for a table

Tags: mysql, sql, cursor, procedure

I am new to writing procedures , I have checked some of the stackoverflow posts but there is no post found to delete all foreign keys for a specific table.

I have a written below procedure.

```
drop procedure if exists remove_foreign_key;

delimiter ;;

create procedure remove_foreign_key(vTableName varchar(128)) begin
if exists (select table_name from information_schema.columns where table_schema=database() and table_name = vTableName) then

(SELECT concat('ALTER TABLE ', TABLE_NAME, ' DROP FOREIGN KEY ', CONSTRAINT_NAME, ';') 
FROM information_schema.key_column_usage 
WHERE table_schema=database() and TABLE_NAME = vTableName
AND referenced_table_name IS NOT NULL);

end if;
end if;
end;;

delimiter ;

call remove_foreign_key('my_table_name');
```

above query return me all queries(number of foreign keys that table contains) which needs to be executed, but I want to execute them one by one.I have read about cursor but not sure about its implementation.can someone help?

Comment: So for every foreign key, you want to launch the procedure but one by one?

Comment: no, for every table

Comment: Okay so use a cursor on the table, that will fetch the table and then launch the procedure. It's a loop procedure for every table so ?

Comment: Please check link I hope it helpful to solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43044683/how-to-drop-all-foreign-keys-from-a-sql-server-database

Answer (score 1):

below is the mysql procedure to delete the foreign keys of some specific table's, hope it helps.you have to pass your table name in call and booom , your foreign keys are deleted for those tables.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS remove_foreign_key;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE remove_foreign_key(vTableName varchar(128))
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE cName VARCHAR(64);
  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
          SELECT DISTINCT CONSTRAINT_NAME
          FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Key_COLUMN_USAGE
          WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME = vTableName
          AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME IS NOT NULL;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;
  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

  OPEN cur;

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO cName;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    SET @sql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',vTableName,' DROP FOREIGN KEY ',cName,';');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur;

  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
  COMMIT;
  SET AUTOCOMMIT=1;
END ;;

DELIMITER ;

call remove_foreign_key('table_name1');
call remove_foreign_key('table_name2');
```